# how to save firebase auth between scenes

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, proyecto26.restclient

Hello people im new with Unity and C#.
I have this script to create/login users and post in firebase database (with email and password).
I copied it from a youtube tutorial with a little few modifications

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FullSerializer;
using Proyecto26;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Serialization;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class PlayerScores : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    public InputField getScoreText;

    public InputField emailText;
    public InputField usernameText;
    public InputField passwordText;

    private System.Random random = new System.Random();

    User user = new User();

    private string databaseURL = "testingurl";
    private string AuthKey = "testingapikey";

    public static fsSerializer serializer = new fsSerializer();


    public static int playerScore;
    public static string playerName;

    private string idToken;

    public static string localId;

    private string getLocalId;


    private void Start()
    {
        playerScore = random.Next(0, 101);
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + playerScore;
    }

    public void OnSubmit()
    {
        PostToDatabase();
        Debug.Log("datos subidos a database");
    }

    public void OnGetScore()
    {
        GetLocalId();
    }

    private void UpdateScore()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + user.userScore;
    }

    private void PostToDatabase(bool emptyScore = false, string idTokenTemp = "")
    {
        if (idTokenTemp == "")
        {
            idTokenTemp = idToken;
        }

        User user = new User();

        if (emptyScore)
        {
            user.userScore = 0;
        }

        RestClient.Put(databaseURL + "/" + localId + ".json?auth=" + idTokenTemp, user);
    }

    private void RetrieveFromDatabase()
    {
        RestClient.Get<User>(databaseURL + "/" + getLocalId + ".json?auth=" + idToken).Then(response =>
        {
            user = response;
            UpdateScore();
        });
    }

    public void SignUpUserButton()
    {
        SignUpUser(emailText.text, usernameText.text, passwordText.text);
    }

    public void SignInUserButton()
    {
        SignInUser(emailText.text, passwordText.text);

    }

    private void SignUpUser(string email, string username, string password)
    {
        string userData = "{\"email\":\"" + email + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\",\"returnSecureToken\":true}";
        RestClient.Post<SignResponse>("https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + AuthKey, userData).Then(
            response =>
            {
                string emailVerification = "{\"requestType\":\"VERIFY_EMAIL\",\"idToken\":\"" + response.idToken + "\"}";
                RestClient.Post(
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getOobConfirmationCode?key=" + AuthKey,
                    emailVerification);
                localId = response.localId;
                playerName = username;
                PostToDatabase(true, response.idToken);
                Debug.Log("SingUp Correcto");

            }).Catch(error =>
            {
                Debug.Log("falta email/password");
                Debug.Log(error);
            });
    }

    private void SignInUser(string email, string password)
    {
        string userData = "{\"email\":\"" + email + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\",\"returnSecureToken\":true}";
        RestClient.Post<SignResponse>("https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=" + AuthKey, userData).Then(
            response =>
            {
                string emailVerification = "{\"idToken\":\"" + response.idToken + "\"}";
                RestClient.Post(
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=" + AuthKey,
                    emailVerification).Then(
                    emailResponse =>
                    {

                        fsData emailVerificationData = fsJsonParser.Parse(emailResponse.Text);
                        EmailConfirmationInfo emailConfirmationInfo = new EmailConfirmationInfo();
                        serializer.TryDeserialize(emailVerificationData, ref emailConfirmationInfo).AssertSuccessWithoutWarnings();

                        if (emailConfirmationInfo.users[0].emailVerified)
                        {
                            idToken = response.idToken;
                            localId = response.localId;
                            GetUsername();
                            Debug.Log("Login Correcto");
                            SceneManager.LoadScene("SignInEdit"); //para logear correctamente solo necesita que el email y password sean correctos, el username no importa.
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Log("You are stupid, you need to verify your email dumb");
                        }
                    });

            }).Catch(error =>
            {
                Debug.Log(error);
            });
    }

    private void GetUsername()
    {
        RestClient.Get<User>(databaseURL + "/" + localId + ".json?auth=" + idToken).Then(response =>
        {
            playerName = response.userName;
        });
    }

    private void GetLocalId()
    {
        RestClient.Get(databaseURL + ".json?auth=" + idToken).Then(response =>
        {
            var username = getScoreText.text;

            fsData userData = fsJsonParser.Parse(response.Text);
            Dictionary<string, User> users = null;
            serializer.TryDeserialize(userData, ref users);

            foreach (var user in users.Values)
            {
                if (user.userName == username)
                {
                    getLocalId = user.localId;
                    RetrieveFromDatabase();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }).Catch(error =>
        {
            Debug.Log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

my problem is I cant save my firebase login between scenes, When I change scene I cant interact anymore with my firebase database.
I tried make a dontdestroyonload script and add a unity gameobject what is containing my PlayerScore script, but dont worked.

I readed im need to store my userid in a static variable to call it from anywhere but I dont know how because im prettly new with c# coding

Can someone give some guidance?, thanks.
PS: the script of above need another 3 script to works, where store/get some values.
If is necessary I add them.

Answer (score 3):

I think that there might be some confusion here as I see a reference to the [official Firebase Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity) mixed with raw REST calls in [RestClient](https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient). I'll answer this assuming that you're ok with using the [Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup). This is a far simpler integration than attempting to manually use the Firebase SDK (and gets you nice benefits - such as local caching).

1) Firebase Authentication

Once Firebase Authentication is initialized, `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser` will always contain your currently signed in user or `null` if the user is not signed in. This value is actually stored in C++ and accessed through C#, meaning that it doesn't actually know about or abide by Unity's typical object lifecycles. That means that once you've signed in a user, this value will always hold the current user without the need to persist it across scene boundaries. In fact, this value is even preserved across runs of your game (meaning that your players don't have to log in every time).

A warning about this though: `CurrentUser` is updated asynchronously -- that is that there is no real guarantee that `CurrentUser` is up to date -- so it's generally safe to register a `StateChanged` listener as Puf suggested [from the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users):

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user;

// Handle initialization of the necessary firebase modules:
void InitializeFirebase() {
  Debug.Log("Setting up Firebase Auth");
  auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
  auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
  AuthStateChanged(this, null);
}

// Track state changes of the auth object.
void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) {
  if (auth.CurrentUser != user) {
    bool signedIn = user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
    if (!signedIn && user != null) {
      Debug.Log("Signed out " + user.UserId);
    }
    user = auth.CurrentUser;
    if (signedIn) {
      Debug.Log("Signed in " + user.UserId);
    }
  }
}

void OnDestroy() {
  auth.StateChanged -= AuthStateChanged;
  auth = null;
}
```

I would highly recommend watching my [tutorial on Firebase Authentication](https://youtu.be/52yUcKLMKX0) to see how I think about integrating this with a game. The [link you shared](https://codeshare.io/2KxBOP) is appropriate, but I'm a little curious about the various REST calls I see in your code.

If you're using the [Firebase Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start), [email/password authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/password-auth) should be as easy as:

```
auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
  if (task.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
    return;
  }
  if (task.IsFaulted) {
    Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
    return;
  }

  // Firebase user has been created.
  Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
  Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
      newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
});
```

to create a user and

```
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
  if (task.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
    return;
  }
  if (task.IsFaulted) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
    return;
  }

  Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
  Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
      newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
});
```

to sign them in. That is, there should be no need to use [RestClient](https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient).

2) Realtime Database

Once you're authenticated, any calls to the [Firebase Realtime Database SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start) will automatically use the `CurrentUser` value (as I mentioned before - it persists on the C++ side of the SDK).

If you're hoping to use [rules to secure user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) such as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then [writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data):

```
Database.DefaultInstance.GetReference($"/users/{FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId}/mySecret").SetValueAsync("flowers");
```

should just work.

I hope that all helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Hello Patrick, Glad to see you here, I have seen your youtube videos.
seeing that using rest calls to make signup/in make problems, I tried to write entirely with firebase sdk for unity.
I found a good tutorial for the sdk. now all its working like a charm. I only have a problem I dont know how implement the "send email verification", I've seen his documentation.
but i am not sure if implement in signup function or SignIn function.
If you can help me, I appreciate.
I have this script for SignUp
https://codeshare.io/5zzv0N

And this script for LogIn:
https://codeshare.io/5OxALW

Comment: **new:** I made some progress, I can send email verification now, but I need to edit my signIn  function to prevent login without verify the email.
Can help me to edit my SignInHandler?.
this are my scripts:

SignUp: (I added email verification in **CreateUserWithEmailAsync()** function
https://codeshare.io/2KxQEo

SignIn:
https://codeshare.io/5zzbAb

AuthManager:
https://codeshare.io/anZwoM

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? As far as user verification, I think you're doing it all right at a cursory glance. Game-wise, you can always check "IsEmailVerified" https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/firebase-user#isemailverified on startup and reroute to a "please verify email screen" instead of moving the user to a game. And you can use rules to prevent non-verified users from interacting with your backend ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth - see email_verified)

Comment: Hi, thats is my problem, I cant realize the way of manage IsEmailverified value changes, always is false, If I logout from the app and enter again I get IsEmailVerified true, after that I can load my scenes, but I dont want logout after registering.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDK automatically persists the authentication state, and tries to restore it automatically too. You'll just need to write code to pick it up, which involves attaching a listener to the auth state.

See the first snippet in the Firebase documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting a listener on the Auth object:
>
> ```
> Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
> Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user;
>
> // Handle initialization of the necessary firebase modules:
> void InitializeFirebase() {
>   Debug.Log("Setting up Firebase Auth");
>   auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
>   auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
>   AuthStateChanged(this, null);
> }
>
> // Track state changes of the auth object.
> void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) {
>   if (auth.CurrentUser != user) {
>     bool signedIn = user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
>     if (!signedIn && user != null) {
>       Debug.Log("Signed out " + user.UserId);
>     }
>     user = auth.CurrentUser;
>     if (signedIn) {
>       Debug.Log("Signed in " + user.UserId);
>     }
>   }
> }
>
> void OnDestroy() {
>   auth.StateChanged -= AuthStateChanged;
>   auth = null;
> }
> ```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. I readed the documentation but I dont know how implement it, Sorry.
I tried this script:
https://codeshare.io/2KxBOP
And I attached to an empty object of my second scene (the first scene have the login script), but I dont think that is the way.
can you explain me this part: 
**You'll just need to write code to pick it up, which involves attaching a listener to the auth state.**

Comment: That code snippet looks fine to me. Your `AuthStateChanged` method should be called once or twice when the `GetUSER` gets triggered. Is that not happening? (I'm not a Unity expert btw, so hope I'm getting the terms right)

Comment: yes. AuthStateChanged is initiated.
I checked with a debug log there:
void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        **Debug.Log("iniciando authstatechanged");**
        if (auth.CurrentUser != user)
        code continues......
but the statement "if" not are running aparently.